# How to nest switch outside and inside?

Tags: powershell

suppose i have the following param cmdlet

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeOne,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeAll,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$View
)
```

suppose i need a `foreach` for `ChangeAll` and `View`, but not for `ChangeOne`. How do i nest the switch statement in this case?

pseudocode of what im looking for...is this how i do it?

```
switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
{
        'ChangeOne'
        {...}

 foreach ($server in $Servers)
 {
     switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
     {
        'ChangeAll'
         {...}
        'View'
         {...}
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an IF statement and the `-in` operator.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeOne,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeAll,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$View
)

if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -in 'View','ChangeAll') {
    foreach () {
    }
}
```

You could take a similar approach with the `-notin` operator. With `-notin`, if you chose to add more parameter sets in the future, they would automatically evaluate to true.

```
if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -notin 'ChangeOne') {
    foreach () {
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to continue using the `Switch` and setting an default condition.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeOne', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeOne,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ChangeAll', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$ChangeAll,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$View
)

switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    'ChangeOne' { }
    Default {
       foreach () {}
    }
}
```

Comment: so inside the foreach, can i retain this as well:      switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
     {
        'ChangeAll'
         {...}
        'View'
         {...}
     }

Comment: Yes. You could. What is the overall goal here?

Comment: the overall goal is whatever the user passes as the switch it would execute particular section of code

Comment: Are you just trying to not repeat identical foreach statements in multiple places? If so, you may want to change your switch statements a little or go with an if statement.

Comment: in other words even the ChangeAll and View switches have different code sections but they are both in the foreach($server in $Servers), on the other hand ChnageOne does not require to be in the foreach() because i am passing a server to it separately as user input

Comment: You can use the default condition of a switch statement to execute if your conditions are not met. So if ChangeOne is not a parameter, it will execute. I don't see why your original idea doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193338/discussion-between-adminofthings-and-cataster).

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty straightforward approach. Check if `$ChangeAll` or `$View` are specified. If not then this will be `$ChangeOne`

```
if($ChangeAll -or $View){
   foreach ...
} else { 
   # ChangeOne will go here
   ...
}
```

Comment: so inside the foreach, can i retain this as well: switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) { 'ChangeAll' {...} 'View' {...} }

Comment: @Cataster Sure you can, but I do not see much reasons to use `switch` for a single condition. You could use single `if` inside of `foreach`.